# HDCP broken over DisplayPort

Tags: windows-10, nvidia-graphics-card, intel-graphics, displayport, hdcp

While trying to watch a movie in HD on Amazon, I saw an error that my system doesn't support HDCP.  It does.  The topology:

Laptop (Lenovo T480) -> Docking Station -> DisplayPort 1.4 (2 of them) -> Monitors HDMI Input (via passive adapter cable)

This same configuration worked on a previous laptop running Windows 7, but isn't working on this new laptop running Windows 10.  The laptop has Intel UHD Graphics 620, drivers were up-to-date and I updated them just now for good measure.  Also on this laptop is NVIDIA GeoForce MX150.

The Intel Graphics Control Panel reports the adapters are connected via DisplayPort.

[image: Intel Graphics Control Panel]

However, if I run ArcSoft BD & 3D Assistant (suggested on another forum), it indicates that my monitors are connected via an analog connector.

[image: ArcSoft BD & 3D Assistant]

No other monitors other than my two DisplayPort connected monitors are detected.

[image: Only two monitors...]

How can I debug this problem?  What are some other things to check?

**Edit:** Just to clarify, playback is fine when not docked.  The issue is at the dock or beyond.

Comment: Your issue is caused by that adapter.  It could also be the docking station.

Comment: @Ramhound The DisplayPort-to-HDMI cable?  Doubtful... I've used these cables in this exact configuration with HDCP before, with no issues.  Previous laptop was a Lenovo T440p, also with Intel Graphics and an Nvidia card, also with a docking station with a pair of DisplayPort outputs.

Comment: @Ramhound Yeah, the issue is definitely post-dock.  Undocked, it's fine.

Comment: It’s which revision of hdmi to which revision of DisplayPort?  Edit your question

Comment: DisplayPort 1.4 on the docking station to unknown HDMI revision on the monitors.  Monitors (Sceptre X246W-1080P) are from around 2011 and support up to 1080p60.

Comment: Well only certain versions of hDMi support hdcp so it’s sort of important.  More important is the specifications of the cable

Comment: @Ramhound The monitors and these exact cables were attached to an older laptop/dock that properly supported HDCP.  The support is there in the hardware at that point.  I'm hoping to find some sort of other way to debug this issue.  This ArcSoft software reports that an analog output is being used, which isn't true.  I'm thinking that something is being misreported somewhere.  I was hoping to figure out how to determine that so I can figure out how to fix it.  There seems to be little in the way of diagnostics for this on Windows 10... at least I can't find it.

Comment: How you would diagnose it is identical to how it would be done on Windows 7